# How to read a file into textview with proper displaying as like in text file?

Tags: android, textview

How to read a file into textview with proper displaying as like in text file?
I can able to read the file into textview.
But displaying as like in the Text file.
My Original Text File:

```
Testing this 1

Satheeshisdf sdf asdfsdfasd fasdfsdfsd
i can able to do it.

Trying it                         thats all.`
```

But displaying like this:

```
i can able to do it.

Trying it                         thats all.`
```

Layout:

```
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_weight="1.0">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/subtitletv"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
/>
```

Program:

```
subtitletv = (TextView)findViewById("R.id.t");
try {
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(selectedfile);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = null;
        try {
            while(br.readLine()!=null)
            {
                line =br.readLine();
                subtitletv.append(line);
                subtitletv.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Update1:**
But now i can not able to read large file(50KB).
Small file loading well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only appending every other line because you are reading two lines at a time...

```
while(br.readLine()!=null) // THIS READS FIRST LINE THEN THIRD LINE
{
    line = br.readLine(); // THIS READS SECOND LINE THEN FOURTH AND SO ON
    subtitletv.append(line);
    subtitletv.append("\n");
}
```

Use...

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    subtitletv.append(line);
    subtitletv.append("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reading a line from `br` twice per loop iteration. Only read once. Also, make sure you close the `FileReader` in a `finally` block. For example:

```
subtitletv = (TextView)findViewById("R.id.t");
FileReader fr = null;
try {
    fr = new FileReader(selectedfile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (null != line) {
        subtitletv.append(line);
        subtitletv.append("\n");
        line = br.readLine();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (null != fr) {
        try {
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man.It is working.But now i cant able to read large file(30KB).How to do.

Comment: Activity not responding. with two button wait and ok

Comment: Ok, that's because reading a file can be quite a long process, and you're reading the file on the UI thread. The Android OS is getting upset about that and letting you know. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html.

Comment: Your file loading code needs to be executed on a different thread to the UI thread. See http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#threading.

Comment: This might be too late for answering, But anyway you could use Async Task for reading a file. Async Task does all the things in background Thread and in this way keeps your app responsive.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html